# Merge Replication with Static Filters - Does not Delete from the subscriber database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I have a merge replication setup, I have applied static filters so as to send only specific rows to the subscribers from a publisher (table) say 'X' the filter is " where Name Starts with ( Select sub-query which returns 'T') ". Now after sync the filters are applied and the rows are synced. E.g: The subscribers will have the following 3 rows.

- ID Name
- 1 Tom
- 2 Tiger
- 3 Tim

Now i go to the Publisher and delete the row 3. And sync again. The deletion is not propagated to the subscriber, and the subscriber still shows the 3rd row. What setting am I missing ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466090/sql-server-static-row-replication-with-updates-based-on-changing-column-value This link has a similar issue mentioned. But no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys found found the problem to my own query. It is documented in the article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324362 .
Sub-Queries do not work in the expected fashion with merge replication.